# iOS PWA splash screen

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I tried to create splash for my PWA using the code below:

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Snappfood"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#ffffff"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash/launch-640x1136.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash/launch-750x1334.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/splash/launch-2436x1125.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash/launch-1242x2208.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash/launch-1125x2436.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/splash/launch-1792x828.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/splash/launch-828x1792.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash/launch-1536x2048.png" media="(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash/launch-1668x2224.png" media="(min-device-width: 834px) and (max-device-width: 834px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash/launch-2048x2732.png" media="(min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/splash/launch-1334x750.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/splash/launch-1242x2688.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/splash/launch-2208x1242.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/splash/launch-2732x2048.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash/launch-2688x1242.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/splash/launch-2224x1668.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/splash/launch-2048x1536.png"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ff00a4"/>
```

you can access to my working project from [here](https://stagingm.snappfood.ir)

but splash is not working on iOS devices.
can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Glad to see snappfood team member, Which version of iOS are you testing on? as I know  **App Manifest and Service Workers** are not working on iOS 10 and before.

Comment: @BeHappy thanks ;) 
I'm testing on ios 13.4.1

Comment: I tested on iOS 13 and *snappfood* logo show up at first and I saw your splash image asset, and they are same.

Comment: no, that's in-app splash, which we show for calling load API, I need to show it before app is ready. this code , I placed here, is not in this address, you can test it too. new.snappfood.ir @BeHappy